# Is it possible to create a form that has optional fields?

Tags: 2010, custom-form

I am a total noob when it comes to SharePoint (and 2010 in particular) although I have extensive experience doing web development. My question is that I would like to create a form which has question they must answer, but has the option to add additional information through additional fields?

An example of this would be a user entering info about a particular medication and one of the fields is how it can be taken. The user would select from a list of options (ie orally, injection, etc.), but for each option that they select, they **must enter additional** information about that selected method.

What I would do normally (when developing websites in my previous life) is to create a form that would allow the user to select a delivery method and then expand a hidden form in which they could enter the details for that method. Then beneath that I would have a button that would say "Add Another Delivery Method" and repeat the process. Is this possible to do with SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to ask a couple of questions here, so I will attempt to answer as best as I can.

It is possible to create a form with a question they must answer, along with an optional field.

You can do it using out of the box SharePoint forms, by going to List Settings and then selecting the column you want required. You can setup validation on this field, including making it required.

If you only want certain fields required based on other selections (in the case that they **must enter additional** information, you can use a formula similar to this one:

```
=IF([Column1]="Orally",IF([Column2]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)
```

Basically, the formula above says "If Column1 is equal to orally, check if Column2 is blank and if Column2 is blank return true, else return false. Otherwise, return true.

Finally, I do not know of a solution to suit your "Add Another ..." method using out of the box SharePoint forms. I normally use InfoPath forms for this, with Repeating fields.

I do not have experience with Nintex forms, so I am not sure if it is possible using that Platform.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will look into the repeating fields function of  InfoPath.